# How to change values of td's inside tr's corresponding to checked checkboxes after Approve button has been clicked?

Tags: jquery

I want to change status of those rows that were checked from "For Approval" to "Approved" and checkboxes be disabled after the Approve button has been clicked.

[image]

Code below is already working at the back end that is, db values update. For now, when user clicks the Approve button it only updates db values but nothing is changed at the front end.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#btnApprove').click(function(){
        let num_of_checks = $(".checkboxes:checked").length;
        if (num_of_checks < 1){ 
            alert("Please check which DPR to approve.");
            return false;
        }
        $('#btnApprove').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning');
        $('#btnApprove').text('Approving...');
        let arr=[];
        $("input:checkbox[name*=check]:checked").each(function(){
            arr.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/approve_dpr2') ?>',
            type:'post',
            dataType:'text',
            data:{ dpr_list: arr },
        }).done(function(data){
            $('#btnApprove').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
            $('#btnApprove').text('Approve');
            // console.log(JSON.parse(data).msg);
        }).error(function(xx){
                console.log('Got Error.');
        });
    });

    $('#btnDisApprove').click(function(){
        let num_of_checks = $(".checkboxes:checked").length;
        if (num_of_checks < 1){ 
            alert("Please check which DPR to disapprove.");
            return false;
        }
        $('#btnDisApprove').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning');
        $('#btnDisApprove').text('Disapproving...');
        let arr=[];
        $("input:checkbox[name*=check]:checked").each(function(){
            arr.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/disapprove_dpr2') ?>',
            type:'post',
            dataType:'text',
            data:{ dpr_list: arr },
        }).done(function(data){
            $('#btnDisApprove').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
            $('#btnDisApprove').text('Disapprove');
        }).error(function(xx){
                console.log('Got Error.');
        });
    });

    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        let checked_status = this.checked;
        $('td input[type=checkbox]').not("[disabled]").each(function () {
            this.checked = checked_status;
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: You're not even disabling the checkbox so obviously nothing will change. All I can see here is that you remove/add class, push values in array and that's it. Why not disable the checkbox inside your .each() ?

Comment: In your `.done` method after this line `$('#btnApprove').text('Approve');` add this code `$(".checkboxes:checked").prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: @AkhtarMunir thanks. Now it remains for me to change the statuses of the checked row to Approved.

Comment: You welcome, kindly accept my answer, so that other people can get help from it.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir your answer does not include changing the status from "For Approval" to "Approved"

Comment: Yeah but it's not a big problem, you mean to say the text inside the td to be change to approved ? right ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir yes

Comment: Wait a second....

Comment: Now see the updated answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199012/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-tatskie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in your .done method after the line $('#btnApprove').text('Approve'); add below code

$(".checkboxes:checked").prop("disabled",true);
$("#status").text("Approved"); // update status text in td
```

For changing the status you can do it by giving an id to status `td` and then access that id like this and change the status.

```
$("#status").text("Approved");
```

But if you have multiple ids then give each td an id like this....

```
<td data-id="check-"your php loop primarkey></td>
```

And then do the same thing but return ids from response loop through it or access the ids through `data-id` and then change according.

```
$("#check-"+id).text("Approved"); // here it can be multiple ids so loop through it.
```

To guide you further, let say for example, you have change the status of 3 records, so you can also return the updated record ids from php response, let say it will be an array i-e, in data, loop through it like this...

```
.done(function(data){
        $('#btnApprove').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
        $('#btnApprove').text('Approve');
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    $("#check-"+value).text("Approved");
  });
})
```

But you have to define the primarykey inside table td like I have showed you with `data-id` so that both ids matched and only change the checked statuses. I hope you will understand.